# ArrayList can not be resolved

Tags: java, arraylist

For my class we are creating a bank account using arraylist. I attempted to create a constructor that contains an arraylist but then I receive the error that it can not be resolved. Any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

```
public class Bank {
public Bank() {
    ArrayList<Account> bankArray = new ArrayList<Account>();
}

public void addNewAccount(Account a) {
    bankArray.add(a); //error here
    return;
}

public Account getAccountByIndex(int idx) {
    return bankArray(idx); //error here
}

public ArrayList getAccounts() {
    return bankArray; //error here
}
```

The error that I'm receiving is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
bankArray cannot be resolved

at Bank.addNewAccount(Bank.java:17)
```

Comment: bankArray is a local variable of your constructor. So it is not visible outside of the constructor. You need to make it a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared the `bankArray` inside the `Bank` constructor i.e., the scope is invalid (outside the constructor) i.e., `bankArray` can ONLY be accessed inside the constructor, so declare it as a class level variable like below:

```
    public class Bank {

      //Declare bankArray as instance variable
      ArrayList<Account> bankArray;

      public Bank() {
        this.bankArray=new ArrayList<>();//use <> operator to make it less verbose
      }
      //add other code of the class
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your bankArray, declare like this only exists on the constructor scope. If you want this property accessible for all the class you have to declare it  directly under the class definition :

```
public class Bank {
List <Account> bankArray
public Bank() {
   this.bankArray = new ArrayList<Account>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> For my class we are creating a bank account using arraylist. I
>   attempted to create a constructor that contains an arraylist but then
>   I receive the error that it can not be resolved.

The `ArrayList` below is only visible and accessible within the scope of the constructor.

```
public Bank() {
     ArrayList<Account> bankArray = new ArrayList<Account>();
}
```

to make it global throughout the class you need to do this:

```
public class Bank {
    ArrayList <Account> bankArray;
    public Bank() {
       this.bankArray = new ArrayList<Account>();
    }
}
```